# Using SqlDataSource for searching

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to use sqldatasource for searching in the GridView using a textbox and have *edit*, *update*, and *paging* enabled; however, after successfully searching when I click *update* the filtered GridView doesn't show instead the whole GridView with every data shows up. Thanks and please advise.

Aspx.cs page:

```
 namespace Inventory
{
    public partial class Results : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.10.101.188;Initial Catalog=ActioNetITInventory;User ID=rails.sa;Password=ActioNet1234");
        private String ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ActioNetITInventoryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //BindData();
                //BindData2();
                //BindData3();



            }//end if


        }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {

            BindData();
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }//end page load

        protected void BindData()
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Inventory]";
                    cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);




                    GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    sqlCon.Close();

                }//end using
            }//end using

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            var serial = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex] as GridViewRow;
            //getting row field details

            TextBox Assigned = row.FindControl("txtAssigned") as TextBox;
            TextBox Location = row.FindControl("txtLocation") as TextBox;
            TextBox Notes = row.FindControl("txtNotes") as TextBox;

            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                string sql = "UPDATE Inventory SET Assigned=@Assigned, " + "Location=@Location, Notes=@Notes" + " WHERE Serial = @Serial";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assigned", Assigned.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", Location.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", Notes.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", serial);

                    sqlCon.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlCon.Close();



                }//end using
            }//end using


            status.Visible = true;
            status.Text = "" + Assigned.Text + "has been added successfully!";
            status.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;


            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }
```

Html page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Serial" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="1575px"
         OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowCancelButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Type") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Add" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Make" SortExpression="Make">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMake" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Make") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Model" SortExpression="Model">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Model") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Serial" SortExpression="Serial">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSerial" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Serial") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assigned" SortExpression="Assigned">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAssigned" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Assigned") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAssigned" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Assigned") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAssigned" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Location") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Location") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNotes" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Notes") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%#Bind("Notes") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ActioNetITInventoryConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Inventory] WHERE [Serial] = @Serial" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Inventory] ([Type], [Make], [Model], [Serial], [Assigned], [Location], [Notes]) VALUES (@Type, @Make, @Model, @Serial, @Assigned, @Location, @Notes)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Inventory] WHERE ([Type] = @Type)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Inventory] SET [Type] = @Type, [Make] = @Make, [Model] = @Model, [Assigned] = @Assigned, [Location] = @Location, [Notes] = @Notes WHERE [Serial] = @Serial">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Serial" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Make" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Model" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Serial" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Assigned" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Location" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="typeTextBox" Name="Type" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Make" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Model" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Assigned" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Location" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Serial" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are divorcing your `GridView` control's data source from the `SqlDataSource` control on this line:

```
GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
```

Since in the `BindData()` method you are executing a query with no `WHERE` clause, it is returning all the rows to bind to the grid, as evidenced by these lines:

```
protected void BindData()
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Inventory]";
            cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            sqlCon.Close();
        }//end using
    }//end using
}
```

This effectively trashes your search criteria, because no criteria (`WHERE` clause) is applied to the SQL query.

You need to have your `SqlDataSource` control's `SelectCommand` support both having a "search" value and not having one. One way of doing that is something along the lines of this:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Inventory] WHERE ([Type] = @Type OR [Type] = '')"
```

Adding the `OR` logic to your `WHERE` clause will filter out no rows (assuming that none of your `Type` values are blank and when you omit the search (i.e. blank string in the search textbox).

---

Personally, I would create a method that returned a `DataTable` object and was passed in the search criteria, which constructed two separate SQL statements, based upon whether or not the "search" string was empty or not, like this:

```
private DataTable GetData(string searchTerm)
{
    DataTable dt = null;

    // Check to see if search term is null or empty
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm)
    {
        // Build SQL statement with WHERE clause
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Inventory] 
                                   WHERE [Type] = @searchTermParameter";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@searchTermParameter", searchTerm));
                cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
            }//end using
        }//end using
    }
    else
    {
        // Build SQL statement without WHERE clause,
        // because we are not searching for anything
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Inventory]";
                cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
            }//end using
        }//end using
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Now you can have your `DataBind` method just accept a `DataTable` object and its sole responsibility is to bind data to the `GridView` control, like this:

```
protected void BindData(DataTable dt)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: thanks! Now I'm trying to BindData during postback, but what do I put inside the _BindData()_ argument? 

Code below:

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

     if(!IsPostBack)
 {

       BindData();

}

}`

Comment: @Terrence Sanchez - just call `GetData (string.Empty);`, that will get all the rows, because of the conditional logic in the `GetData` method.

Comment: I did that, however, when I click number two to get to the second page nothing shows. 

Here is the code:
`protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEvenArgs e)
{

GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
GetData(string.Empty);

}//end paging `

Comment: @Terrence Sanchez - you need to call `BindData (string.Empty);` in the page index changing event handler.

Comment: @Terrence Sanchez - sorry meant `BindData (GetData (string.Empty ));`